# Remove/Create labels using For loop in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm planning to create labels using for loop. Every time I select a different option from combo box, the older labels should get deleted and new labels should be created. I use the below code, but getting error.

I use python **3.7.2**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
master = tk.Tk()

class job():
    def fun(self,eventObject):
        print(self.box_value.get())
        dimensions = ['ab', 'bc','cd','de']
        self.labl.destroy()
        z = 20
        for i in range(len(dimensions)):
            self.labl = tk.Label(master, text=dimensions[i])
            self.labl.place(x=z, y=20)
            z = z + 130
    def __init__(self):
        self.box_value=tk.StringVar()
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=self.box_value, state='readonly')
        self.combo['values'] = ['Cd', 'Ale']
        self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun)
        self.combo.current(1)
        self.combo.place(x=80,y=100)

a=job()

master.mainloop()
```

> AttributeError: 'job' object has no attribute 'labl'

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. You're trying to destroy something that doesn't exist. Ask yourself this: what is `self.labl` the very first time `fun` is called?

Comment: I know the widget doesn't exist and that is reason it errors out. But could you please help me achieve my requirement. I googled a lot, but no use.

Comment: How do I get the widget details globally and delete it before creating new widgets in the next iteration?

Comment: You can't get the details of something that doesn't exist. Just initialize `self.labl` to `None`, and then check for it being `None` before trying to delete it.

Comment: I used `try` and `except` for the first loop as the widgets won't be there initially. Thanks any way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it myself, previously I couldn't get the logic to achieve it. But now I'm good, posting the answer for future ref:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
master = tk.Tk()

class job():
    def fun(self,eventObject):
        dimensions = ['gdgd','dfddf','bgsdg']
        try:
            if self.check == 1:
                for i in self.labels:
                    i.destroy()
        except:
            pass
        z = 20
        self.labels=[]
        for i in range(len(dimensions)):
            self.labl = tk.Label(master, text=dimensions[i])
            self.labl.place(x=z, y=20)
            self.labels.append(self.labl)
            z = z + 130
    self.check = 1
def __init__(self):
    self.box_value=tk.StringVar()
    self.combo = ttk.Combobox(master, textvariable=self.box_value, state='readonly')
    self.combo['values'] = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
    self.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.fun)
    self.combo.current(1)
    self.combo.place(x=80,y=100)

a=job()

master.mainloop()
```